# Angular 8 - how does it determine the startup page

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 8 application that displays the login page at startup.

How/what sets this as the startup page? There is only 1 routing module.I looked all over for reference to it but nothing that indicates that this page should show at startup.

What am I missing? Any ideas?

[image]

Here is the app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './pages/home/home.component';
import {DetailsComponent} from './pages/details/details.component';
import {AddComponent} from './pages/add/add.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './pages/login/login.component';
import {SignupComponent} from './pages/signup/signup.component';

import {AuthGuard} from './guards/auth.guard';
import {AppGuard} from './guards/app.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AppGuard]},
   {path: 'details/:city', component: DetailsComponent, canActivate: [AppGuard]},
   {path: 'add', component: AddComponent, canActivate: [AppGuard]},
   {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
   {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
   {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: I would look at `AppGuard` where the redirect to `login` page is most likely defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code you have got your Routes array which shows the components that will be rendered based on the URL or the navigation path taken. Now if you will see the canActivate property there are two guards that you are using  one AppGuard and another AuthGuard. The guards are basically there to protect some of your pages from direct accessibility. If all guards return true, the navigation happens. Example would be when someone is buying something on your website. He should probably be a logged in user and you redirect the customer to the login screen. Read more about it [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) and [authguard](https://angular.io/guide/router).

My initial guess would be to look at AppGuard given that`s there in the canActivate property of your default navigation. Nonetheless check in AuthGuard as well. Will give you a clarity on why you have two guards in your application and what each of them are responsible for. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

At a closer look and understanding of the guards, I do see that the 'AppGuard' redirects to the login page at startup due to not being authenticated yet. It attempts to default to the home page at startup, but then the Appguard is run and indicates that the User has not been authenticated yet so it redirects to the login page.